Determine the smallest degree of monomial in a polynomial given as a black box
As I was reading some papers about black box polynomials and I stumbled upon this question: Determine degree of polynomial given as black box
Essentially we determine the monomial with the largest power.
Now given a polynomial as a black box with coefficients in a finite field as well, can we also determine the degree of the smallest monomial in the polynomial?
Does it follow the same approach presented in the question referenced, but just using smaller numbers approaching zero?
The approach in question:

We can take values
$$P_0(i)=P(i), i=0\dots n,$$
and to calculate differences
$$P_k(j)=P_{k-1}(j+1)-P_{k-1}(j), j=0\dots n-k-1$$
until all $P_k(j)$ became constants.
It is easy to prove that all $P_k=const$ for $k$th order polynomial.

What happens if the coefficients are binary only? Is there than even a faster way. I hope this question is okay and thank you
And on a site note: The author of the question mentions randomized time $O(n)$, but where is the randomness in the approach presented?

The smallest degree monomial of $P$ corresponds to the largest degree monomial of $x^nP\left(\frac 1x\right)$ where $n$ is the degree of $P$.

As for your randomness question, flip a coin after taking each difference. It doesn't effect the calculation, but it is random... (I.e. "randomized $O(n)$" includes "non-random $O(n)$"),
